# Plot only labels in selected positions in matplotlib pie/donut chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following half pie chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6),dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

pie_labels = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"]
pie_values = [1,2,3]
pie_labels.append("Label 0")
pie_values.append(sum(pie_values))  
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white']

wedges, texts = ax.pie(pie_values, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.35), startangle= -90,colors=colors)

for w,lbl in zip(wedges,pie_labels):
    angle = w.theta2
    r=w.r-w.width/2
    x = r*np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle)) 
    y  = r*np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle))
    ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.annotate(lbl, xy=(x,y), size=12, color='k',
                    ha='right', va='center', weight='bold')
```

which produces:
[image]

From the (x,y) coordinates taken from the wedge patch, how do I iterate it, to plot for example only the first and last labels or the first and third labels?
I dont want to create a new list of labels, I am looking to get the position of certain labels. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the labels in a dictionary.  Note that what you call "label 0", in reality is a last invisible wedge that closes the circle. By subtracting `1` from your numbering, key `1` will go to the start of `wedges[0]`, and key `0` to `wedges[-1]` (the last one). Adding a space to the label gives a bit of extra padding.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

pie_labels = {0: "Label 0", 1: "Label 1", 3: "Label 3"}

pie_values = [1, 2, 3]
pie_values.append(sum(pie_values))
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'none']

wedges, texts = ax.pie(pie_values, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.35), startangle=-90, colors=colors)

for key in pie_labels:
    w = wedges[key - 1]
    angle = w.theta2
    r = w.r - w.width / 2
    x = r * np.cos(np.deg2rad(angle))
    y = r * np.sin(np.deg2rad(angle))
    ax.scatter(x, y, facecolor='gold', edgecolor='black', marker='D')
    ax.annotate(pie_labels[key] + " ", xy=(x, y), size=12, color='k',
                ha='right', va='center', weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: labeling wedges of a pie chart]